# “Unexpected Token <” error in HTML while using socket.io via npm

Tags: npm, socket.io

I know this issue has been discussed in an old post. But in that scenario the developer was importing socket.io via a script tag. I am getting the same error on my local build and I have installed socket.io using npm.

Has anyone had a similar issue? How can this be corrected?

Comment: pls share your code

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an npm cache issue for me. After several attempts I was able to resolve this by clearing my npm cache, deleting all of the modules, and then re-running npm install.